# Django pyodbc Latin1_General_CI_AI encoding

Tags: python, sql-server, django, character-encoding, pyodbc

I have a django app using pyodbc to talk to a MS SQL Server Database with Latin1_General_CI_AI encoding. (I have no control over this database and cannot change the encoding.)

The problem is that every string going from Django -> pyodbc has to be encoded:

For example:

```
m = MyModel()
m.foo = 'foo' # Garbage characters are saved
m.foo = 'foo'.encode('latin1') # String is saved correctly
m.save()
```

The second problem is that query strings needs to be encoded too:

```
MyModel.objects.get(name=name) # fails
MyModel.objects.get(name=name.encode('latin1')) # works
```

Is there a more general way I can handle this? Either a Model mixin or DB backend? I see places in Django's SQLCompiler but not sure how to affect it.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing something similar, and had a similar workaround in place.

For me, adding the connection parameter `ClientCharset=utf8` corrected the problem. If using `django-pyodbc` like me, that means adding:

`'OPTIONS': {
    'extra_params': 'ClientCharset=utf8',
}`

to your database configuration settings. If you're using pyodbc directly, then you can just add that to your connection string.

The trick here (from what I can tell) is that your TDS driver is already trying to translate from the source database into an appropriate default encoding for your client to read. Since we're talking Microsoft land here, an appropriate default is ISO 8859-1 (Can't remember if this is exactly Latin-1, or if it is just so close that people don't tend to notice the difference). That's why your workaround works. See [here](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/odbcconnattr.htm) for more.

Django expects databases to be [talking utf-8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#encoding), so all we do here is tell the TDS driver what we want to hear.